# How to check if an edge exist in a Spark Graphx graph

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a Spark Graphx graph, and I want to check wether an edge exists between two vertices or not.
What is the preferred method for doing this in Spark Graphx?

More specifically I would like to count all the edges between all vertices in one list to all vertices in another list.

I tried this:

```
graph.edges.filter { case Edge(src, dst, prop) => ids1.contains(src)&&ids2.contains(dst)}.count
```

where `ids1` and `ids2` are two arrays containing vertex ids. But this doesn't work and I get the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

I'm not very familiar with Graphx so any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me :

```
graph.edges.filter(edge=>( ids.contains(edge.srcId) && ids.contains(edge.dstId))
```